# Matching the index number in attribute name inside nested array braces using regEx

Tags: jquery, regex, arrays, indexing, increment

I need help in RegEx, i want only the index number match inside braces[1] which is text[alphanumeric][index][text] see attribute name below.

```
name="lorem[ipsum_dolor_set-amet-34][1][consectetuer]"
```

I have regex code below that almost work.

```
My Code: [\[^.*\]](\d+)
```

But the result is, it matched the open brace and index **<** [1 **>** instead of index **<** 1 **>** only.

Any answer is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I have no idea what you tried there, but you are matching one out of these characters `[`, `^`, `.`, `*`, `]` followed by one or more digits. Which language or environment are you using this in? Why not just `\[(\d+)\]`? (in which case you'd still need to retrieve the captured contents) or `(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])`?

Comment: Thanks for respond m.buettner, im using jQuery, basically im trying to increment the index inside brace, but if i will use [(\d+)\] only the first decimal will increment which is the 34 number see above code in attribute name, i want only the index will increment thats why i use [^.*\] to ignore the content in first braces. :)

Answer (score 0):

> But the result is, it matched the open brace and index < [1 > instead of index < 1 > only.

I think your regex code is ok, but you are using the first index of your match array.

```
var myString = "name='lorem[ipsum_dolor_set-amet-34][1][consectetuer]'";  
var arr = myString.match(/[\[^.*\]](\d+)/);  
console.log(arr[0] + " " + arr[1]);
```

Comment: im using string.replace(/[\[^.*\]](\d+)/, new ); if i use to match the string that would be fine but i want to replace the index, so in that case it will replace both "[" and "1". and the attribute its look like this name="lorem[ipsum_dolor_set-amet-34]2][consectetuer]"

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the digits from the square brackets:

```
var name = "lorem[ipsum_dolor_set-amet-34][1][consectetuer]";
var regex = /\[([0-9]+)\]/;

if (m = name.match(regex)[1]) {
    console.log(m);
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6SGk/1/).

Comment: thats works fine but i still want to remain the brace so its look like this [1] so only index will change in case.

Comment: @Ruel In the if, you can use this to get `[1]` **:** `m = name.match(regex)[0]`